# Is there graphic editor for AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio just like Eclipse?

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

[image]
In Android Studio 1.0, I can not find a visual editor for AndroidManifest.xml as Eclipse. Is there graphic editor for AndroidManifest in Android Studio?